# Project Zomboid Server Google Compute Engine

Tags: tcp, firewall, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to set up a server using Google Compute Engine but find myself being stuck.

I've installed everything that needs to be installed, I can start the server, no problem.  Only thing is, i'm unable to connect to the server.

I've opened the required ports in a firewall rule (udp:16261; tcp:16262-16270) for all source IP as normal, but when I try to connect, i get this message on the server's console :

> User jet is trying to connect.
>
> Connected new client jet ID # 0 and assigned DL port 16262
>
> testing TCP download port 16262

And it waits and waits, nothin happens.  I'm pretty sure it's because no connection has been requested from the outsite of the network on that specific port (16262) that the outgoing traffic can't be sent, but I was wondering if anyone else has tried to make it work.

Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: can you post the links that you followed? Maybe I can reproduce the issue on my end.

Comment: Hi @George, sure no problem : i've followed the instructions here : http://pzwiki.net/wiki/Multiplayer_FAQ#Linux.

It's a bit outdated tough, as you don't need to specify the _beta_ and _online test_ options when downloading with SteamCMD.

I've got a Server with the same spec at home, and it works fine.  Of course, my router is not as powerfull as the firewall in google compute engine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pzwiki.net/wiki/Dedicated_Server#Connecting_to_the_Server); in the "Forwarding Required Ports" Section:

> Project Zomboid dedicated servers require the following open ports to successfully connect to clients:
>
> - 8766 UDP
> - 16261 UDP

If the client's public ip address is known, you can perform a basic troubleshooting whitin Google Compute Engine using [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging). A basic [query](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/building-queries) returning all the logs containing that ip address as source or destination would be:

```
jsonPayload.connection.src_ip="public-ip-address" OR jsonPayload.connection.dest_ip="public-ip-address"
```

[Firewall Rules Logging](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewall-rules-logging) has to be "on" for every rule involved in the connection. Follow these steps for [Enabling firewall rules logging](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewall-rules-logging#enable).

For troubleshooting purposes an "allow all" Firewall rule can be created and logging enabled on it, that would allow you to see exactly what ports are involved.

Note: If the traffic hitting the firewall rule(s) is too much, it can lead to unanticipated storage costs. Please enable the firewall rules logging just for troubleshooting purposes, don't forget to disable it after you're done.